# how to handle downloads on gecko15 with mozilla xul15 in visual basic?

Tags: .net, mozilla, xulrunner, gecko, geckofx

I am using gecko15 with mozilla xul15 as a web browser on my visual basic application

anyone knows how i can handle downloads please ?

because, when i click on a file to download from that browser nothing happens.

thanks a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Also:
@Form LOad Event:
Add:
AddHandler Gecko.LauncherDialog.Download, AddressOf LauncherDialog_Download

Then
 Private Sub LauncherDialog_Download(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Gecko.LauncherDialogEvent)
e.cancel()
try
catch ex as exception
finally
 e.Navigate(Nothing) 'prevent unusual DM behavior
end try
End Sub

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 0):

This was the headache of all us, not to be able to let user to download a file in embedded (vb net) gecko browser. 'Kixpsider (long live my friend)', an anonymous genius, ended this trouble. Please follow code below in clear format:

```
    Dim objTarget As Gecko.nsILocalFile = Gecko.Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of Gecko.nsILocalFile)("@mozilla.org/file/local;1")
    Dim tmp_Loc As String = Application.StartupPath & "\data"
    Dim sx As Object = Nothing
    Dim fx As String = ""
    Dim saveBox As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim win As Object = Gecko.Xpcom.GetService(Of Gecko.nsIWindowWatcher)("@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1")

    'win.OpenWindow(Nothing, "chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/downloads.xul", "Downloads", "chrome,resizable=yes,hide", Nothing)

    Using tmp As New Gecko.nsAString(tmp_Loc)
        objTarget.InitWithPath(tmp)
    End Using

    If e.Filename.Contains(".") Then
        sx = Strings.Split(e.Filename, ".")
        fx = sx(sx.Length - 1).ToUpper & " File (*." & sx(sx.Length - 1) & ")|*." & sx(sx.Length - 1)
    Else
        fx = "File (*.*)|*.*"
    End If

    savebox.Filter = fx '"HTML File (*.html)|*.html"
    savebox.Title = "Save File:"
    savebox.FileName = e.Filename
    If saveBox.ShowDialog <> System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveBox.FileName) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim source As Gecko.nsIURI = Gecko.IOService.CreateNsIUri(New Uri(e.Url).AbsoluteUri)
    Dim dest As Gecko.nsIURI = Gecko.IOService.CreateNsIUri(New Uri(saveBox.FileName).AbsoluteUri)
    Dim t As Gecko.nsAStringBase = DirectCast(New Gecko.nsAString(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(saveBox.FileName)), Gecko.nsAStringBase)

    Dim persist As Gecko.nsIWebBrowserPersist = Gecko.Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of Gecko.nsIWebBrowserPersist)("@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1")
    Dim DownloadMan As Gecko.nsIDownloadManager = Gecko.Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of Gecko.nsIDownloadManager)("@mozilla.org/download-manager;1")
    Dim downloadX As Gecko.nsIDownload = DownloadMan.AddDownload(0, source, dest, t, e.Mime, 0, Nothing, DirectCast(persist, Gecko.nsICancelable), False)

    If (downloadX IsNot Nothing) Then
        persist.SetPersistFlagsAttribute(2 Or 32 Or 16384)
        persist.SetProgressListenerAttribute(DirectCast(downloadX, Gecko.nsIWebProgressListener))
        persist.SaveURI(source, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, DirectCast(dest, Gecko.nsISupports), Nothing)
    End If
```

Answer (score -1):

'Note: Remove "'"

'      Dim P As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\\tmp"
                        '      If Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(P) Then System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(P)

```
                    '                        Dim objTarget As nsILocalFile = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsILocalFile)("@mozilla.org/file/local;1")
                    '                        Dim tmp_Loc As String = P & "\tmpdload"
                    '                        Using tmp As New nsAString(tmp_Loc)
                    ' objTarget.InitWithPath(tmp)
                    ' End Using

                    ' If e.Filename.Contains(".") Then
                    'S = Strings.Split(e.Filename, ".")
                    'F = S(S.Length - 1).ToUpper & " File (*." & S(S.Length - 1) & ")|*." & S(S.Length - 1)
                    'Else
                    '    F = "File (*.*)|*.*"
                    'End If

                    '    savebox.Filter = F '"HTML File (*.html)|*.html"
                    '    savebox.Title = "Save File:"
                    '    savebox.FileName = e.Filename
                    '    If savebox.ShowDialog = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(savebox.FileName) Then
                    ' Dim source As nsIURI = IOService.CreateNsIUri(New Uri(e.Url).AbsoluteUri)
                    ' Dim dest As nsIURI = IOService.CreateNsIUri(New Uri(savebox.FileName).AbsoluteUri)
                    ' Dim t As nsAStringBase = DirectCast(New nsAString(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(savebox.FileName)), nsAStringBase)
                    '
                    '                       Dim persist As nsIWebBrowserPersist = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIWebBrowserPersist)("@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1")
                    '                       Dim DownloadMan As nsIDownloadManager = Xpcom.CreateInstance(Of nsIDownloadManager)("@mozilla.org/download-manager;1")
                    '                       Dim downloadX As nsIDownload = DownloadMan.AddDownload(0, source, dest, t, e.Mime, 0, Nothing, DirectCast(persist, nsICancelable), False) '

                    '                        If (downloadX IsNot Nothing) Then
                    'persist.SetPersistFlagsAttribute(2 Or 32 Or 16384)
                    'persist.SetProgressListenerAttribute(DirectCast(downloadX, nsIWebProgressListener))
                    'persist.SaveURI(source, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, DirectCast(dest, nsISupports), Nothing)
```

'To show the FF Download Manager:
'Dim win = Xpcom.GetService(Of nsIWindowWatcher)("@mozilla.org/embedcomp/window-watcher;1")
                        '   win.OpenWindow(Nothing, "chrome://mozapps/content/downloads/downloads.xul", "Downloads", "chrome,resizable=yes,hide", Nothing)

Comment: Can you please fix the formatting and explain your answer? Why is the entire code sample commented out?